# Jcanvas coordinates don't start at (0,0)

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas, jcanvas

I'm trying to get my head around HTML 5 canvas, trying jCanvas. 
But i'm experiencing a weird problem.

Im trying to draw an rectangle that should fill the whole canvas using the following code:

HTML

```
<canvas width=600 height=400></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = $("canvas");

//white background in canvas
canvas.drawRect({
        fillStyle: "#FFF",
        x: 0, y: 0,
        width: 600,
        height: 400
 });
```

This outputs a rectangle, but only half the intended size. If i change the x,y coordinates to half width/height, then i get the expected result. But from what I understand x,y should start from top left corner, right?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6x5j/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Answer. 
Apperently canvas needs one additional parameter to count coordinates from top left instead of center.

I changed the js code to:

```
var canvas = $("canvas");
//white background in canvas
canvas.drawRect({
        fillStyle: "#FFF",
        x: 0, y: 0,
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        fromCenter: false
    });
```

And now it works as expected!

You can also change the default behavior by calling this method:

```
$.jCanvas({
    fromCenter: false
});
```

In the beginning of the script

Comment: Nice find. You should accept your own answer. This way the question will be closed.

Comment: I know, but i cant do that in two days!